# Not redirecting to third page directly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have three pages 1.SplashScreen 2.Welcome 3.MainActivity.I want if user enters for first time then he must go in order Splashscreen-Welcome-MainActivity.But if user is entering for second time or later he must go from SplashScreen to MainActivity directly.Problem is that even if user enters second time he goes in same order as first and is not redirected to MainActivity directly.Following is my code-

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        final MainActivity login=new MainActivity(getApplicationContext());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                if (login.isuserLoggedIn()) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Welcome.class));
                    finish();
                }


            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**Welcome.java**

```
public class Welcome extends Activity{


TextView txt;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Welcome.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String IS_User_login = "isuserloggedin";
    static  SharedPreferences app_preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the app's shared preferences

        app_preferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // Get the value for the run counter
        int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);

        // Update the TextView
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("This app has been started " + counter + " times.");

        // Increment the counter
        editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
        editor.commit(); // Very important

    }

    public  MainActivity(final Context applicationContext) {


        app_preferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("usersession",0);

        //Edit pfeff file
        editor = app_preferences.edit();

        editor.apply();
    }

    public MainActivity()
    {

    }

    public static boolean isuserLoggedIn() {
        return app_preferences.getBoolean(IS_User_login,false);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can store the boolean flag in the shared preferences and then show or hide splash screen

Comment: how can i do that? I have done it in isuserLoggedIn()

Comment: No you are doing it wrong

Comment: Wat mistake i am doing?

Comment: let me add one in answer

Comment: add this line in MainActivty  editor.put(IS_User_login, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you don't need any static member to get stored shared preferences. Secondly you are trying to get shared preference value which you have't stored.

Simply, add this in your splash activity

```
    SharedPreferences app_preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

            if (app_preferences.getBoolean("first",false) {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            else {

                app_preferences.edit().putBoolean("first", true).commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Welcome.class));
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: app_preferences.editor.putBoolean("first", true).commit();  showing error at editor in else

Comment: glad to hear -:)

Comment: Thanks :) Finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
  public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {



public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SplashScreen.PREFS_NAME, 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        final MainActivity login=new MainActivity(getApplicationContext());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
       boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);
                if (hasLoggedIn) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else {
//Set "hasLoggedIn" to true first time
editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Welcome.class));
                    finish();
                }


            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);  its not taking putBoolean

Comment: it will take plz try once more

Comment: Have put that line in oncreate its taking now. Trying it

Comment: No its showing putBoolean in red.Have pasted ur code directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

     boolean flag=false;
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);




    SharedPreferences pref = 
    getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        flag=pref.getBoolean("flag", false);







            final MainActivity login=new 
           MainActivity(getApplicationContext());
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity

                    if (login.isuserLoggedIn()) {



        if(!flag)
            {
    flag=true;
    editor.putBoolean("flag", flag);
                editor.commit(); // commit changes

    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

           }else
{
   startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Welcome.class));
                        finish();

}




                    }
                 //   else {

    //                    startActivity(new //Intent(SplashScreen.this,Welcome.class));
     //                   finish();
             //       }


                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would suggest you not to use an anonymous Handler.
As if we close the app the handler still runs and it will crash the app.
So use an handler instance, so you can cancel it on back pressed and in on Destroy method.
Rest you can use the Shared Preferences to save the state.